HTTPS proxy server gets timeout
I am trying to implement an HTTP/HTTPS proxy server in Kotlin (for Android), and it works as expected for HTTP but for HTTPS requests it gets  The connection has timed out all the time.
The client connection with the server is made but I didn't get any error thrown in my implementation and here is the full code of the proxy server:

interface ProxyPortListener {
    fun setProxyPort(port: Int)
}

class ProxyServer(private val context: Context) : Thread() {

    var countOfConnectionsDone = 0

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ProxyServer"
        private const val CONNECT = "CONNECT"
        private const val HTTP_OK = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        private const val HEADER_CONNECTION = "connection"
        private const val HEADER_PROXY_CONNECTION = "proxy-connection"
    }

    private val threadExecutor: ExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
    var isRunning: Boolean = false
        private set

    private var serverSocket: ServerSocket? = null
    private var port: Int = -1
    private var callback: ProxyPortListener? = null

    init {
        startServer()
    }

    fun setCallback(callback: ProxyPortListener) {
        this.callback = callback
        if (port != -1) {
            callback.setProxyPort(port)
        }
    }

    override fun run() {
        try {
            serverSocket =
                ServerSocket(Prefs.getProxyPort(context), 0, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"))
            port = serverSocket!!.localPort
            callback?.setProxyPort(port)
            isRunning = true
            Log.d(TAG, "Proxy server started on port $port")
            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    val socket = serverSocket!!.accept()
                    Log.d(TAG, "Accepted connection from ${socket.inetAddress}")
                    val proxyConnection = ProxyConnection(socket)
                    threadExecutor.execute(proxyConnection)
                } catch (e: SocketException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket exception while running server", e)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to start proxy server", e)
        }
    }

    fun startServer() {
        if (!isRunning && state == Thread.State.NEW) {
            start()
        }
    }

    fun stopServer() {
        isRunning = false
        serverSocket?.close()
        serverSocket = null
        try {
            join() // Wait for the thread to finish executing
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to stop proxy server", e)
        }
    }



    private inner class ProxyConnection(private val connection: Socket) : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            try {
                val requestLine = getLine(connection.getInputStream())
                val splitLine = requestLine.split(" ")
                if (splitLine.size < 3) {
                    connection.close()
                    return
                }

                val requestType = splitLine[0]
                var urlString = splitLine[1]
                val httpVersion = splitLine[2]

                val url: URI
                val host: String
                val port: Int
                var server: Socket? = null

                if (requestType == CONNECT) {
                    // Handle HTTPS connections using CONNECT method
                    val parts = urlString.split(":")
                    host = parts[0]
                    port = if (parts.size > 1) parts[1].toInt() else 443
                    try {
                        server = Socket(host, port)
                        sendLine(connection, HTTP_OK)
                        SocketConnect.connect(connection, server)
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error handling CONNECT request", e)
                        connection.close()
                    }
                    return
                } else {
                    // Handle HTTP connections
                    try {
                        url = URI(urlString)
                        host = url.host
                        port = if (url.port < 0) 80 else url.port
                    } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
                        connection.close()
                        return
                    }
                }

                // Create socket based on proxy configuration
                val proxy = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(URI(urlString)).firstOrNull()
                if (proxy != Proxy.NO_PROXY) {
                    val inetSocketAddress = proxy?.address() as InetSocketAddress
                    server = Socket(inetSocketAddress.hostName, inetSocketAddress.port)
                } else {
                    server = Socket(host, port)
                }

                // Forward request and response
                sendAugmentedRequestToHost(connection, server, requestType, url, httpVersion)
                SocketConnect.connect(connection, server)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem Proxying", e)
            } finally {
                try {
                    connection.close()
                } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing connection", ioe)
                }
            }
        }

        private fun sendAugmentedRequestToHost(
            src: Socket,
            dst: Socket,
            httpMethod: String,
            uri: URI,
            httpVersion: String
        ) {
            sendRequestLineWithPath(dst, httpMethod, uri, httpVersion)
            filterAndForwardRequestHeaders(src, dst)
            sendLine(dst, "Connection: close")
            sendLine(dst, "")
        }

        private fun sendRequestLineWithPath(
            server: Socket,
            requestType: String,
            absoluteUri: URI,
            httpVersion: String
        ) {
            val absolutePath = getAbsolutePathFromAbsoluteURI(absoluteUri)
            val outgoingRequestLine = "$requestType $absolutePath $httpVersion"
            sendLine(server, outgoingRequestLine)
        }

        private fun getAbsolutePathFromAbsoluteURI(uri: URI): String {
            val rawPath = uri.rawPath ?: "/"
            val rawQuery = uri.rawQuery?.let { "?$it" } ?: ""
            val rawFragment = uri.rawFragment?.let { "#$it" } ?: ""
            return "$rawPath$rawQuery$rawFragment"
        }

        private fun getLine(inputStream: InputStream): String {
            val buffer = StringBuilder()
            var byteBuffer = inputStream.read()
            if (byteBuffer < 0) return ""
            while (byteBuffer != '\n'.code && byteBuffer >= 0) {
                if (byteBuffer != '\r'.code) {
                    buffer.append(byteBuffer.toChar())
                }
                byteBuffer = inputStream.read()
            }
            return buffer.toString()
        }

        private fun sendLine(socket: Socket, line: String) {
            try {
                if (!socket.isClosed) {
                    val os = socket.getOutputStream()
                    os.write(line.toByteArray())
                    os.write('\r'.code)
                    os.write('\n'.code)
                    os.flush()
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot write to closed socket")
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while writing to socket: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

        private fun filterAndForwardRequestHeaders(src: Socket, dst: Socket) {
            var line: String
            do {
                line = getLine(src.getInputStream())
                if (line.isNotEmpty() && !shouldRemoveHeaderLine(line)) {
                    sendLine(dst, line)
                }
            } while (line.isNotEmpty())
        }

        private fun shouldRemoveHeaderLine(line: String): Boolean {
            val colIndex = line.indexOf(":")
            if (colIndex != -1) {
                val headerName = line.substring(0, colIndex).trim()
                if (headerName.equals(HEADER_CONNECTION, ignoreCase = true)
                    || headerName.equals(HEADER_PROXY_CONNECTION, ignoreCase = true)
                ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    class SocketConnect(private val from: Socket, private val to: Socket) : Thread() {
        private val buffer = ByteArray(512)

        override fun run() {
            val inputStream = from.getInputStream()
            val outputStream = to.getOutputStream()
            try {
                var bytesRead: Int
                while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                }
            } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun connect(first: Socket, second: Socket) {
                val sc1 = SocketConnect(first, second)
                val sc2 = SocketConnect(second, first)
                sc1.start()
                sc2.start()
                try {
                    sc1.join()
                    sc2.join()
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


What could be the reason for this timeout error?

So I created a function that streams data as they are in CONNET (HTTPS case):
   @Throws(IOException::class)
        private fun skipToRequestBody(socket: Socket) {
            while (getLine(socket.getInputStream()).isNotEmpty())
        }

and here is adjusted run function:
override fun run() {
            try {
                countOfConnectionsDone = NetworkUtils.checkIfCountExceeded(countOfConnectionsDone, context)
                val requestLine = getLine(connection.getInputStream())
                val splitLine = requestLine.split(" ")
                if (splitLine.size < 3) {
                    connection.close()
                    return
                }

                val requestType = splitLine[0]
                var urlString = splitLine[1]
                val httpVersion = splitLine[2]

                val url: URI
                val host: String
                val port: Int
                var server: Socket? = null

                if (requestType == CONNECT) {
                    val hostPortSplit: List<String> = urlString.split(":")
                    host = hostPortSplit[0]

                    // Use default SSL port if not specified. Parse it otherwise
                    port = if (hostPortSplit.size < 2) {
                        443
                    } else {
                        try {
                            hostPortSplit[1].toInt()
                        } catch (nfe: NumberFormatException) {
                            connection.close()
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    urlString = "Https://" + attr.host + ":" + port
                } else {
                    // Handle HTTP connections
                    try {
                        url = URI(urlString)
                        host = url.host
                        port = if (url.port < 0) 80 else url.port
                    } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
                        connection.close()
                        return
                    }
                }

                // Create socket based on proxy configuration
                val proxy = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(URI(urlString)).firstOrNull()
                if (proxy != Proxy.NO_PROXY) {
                    val inetSocketAddress = proxy?.address() as InetSocketAddress
                    server = Socket(inetSocketAddress.hostName, inetSocketAddress.port)
                } else {
                    server = Socket(host, port)
                }

                // Forward request and response
                if (requestType == CONNECT) {
                    skipToRequestBody(connection);
                    // No proxy to respond so we must.
                    sendLine(connection, HTTP_OK);
                } else {
                    sendAugmentedRequestToHost(connection, server, requestType, URI(urlString), httpVersion)
                }
                SocketConnect.connect(connection, server)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Problem Proxying", e)
            } finally {
                try {
                    connection.close()
                } catch (ioe: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing connection", ioe)
                }
            }
        }

